# Parsing filename with a regular expression in TypeScript (also plain nodejs), surprisingly results in null

Tags: node.js, regex, typescript

I have a very simple construct which should parse a filename for it's language.

My `language.ts` model looks like this:

```
export interface Language {
  language?: string;
  region?: string;
}
```

The function which should parse the filename ..

import { Language } from '../models/language';

```
const FILENAME_REGEX = /(?<=\.)(?<language>[a-z]{2})(\-(?<region>[A-Z]{2}))?(?=\.)/gim;

export const parseFilename = (filename: string): Language => {
  const result = FILENAME_REGEX.exec(filename);
  if (result?.groups) {
    return {
      language: result.groups['language'],
      region: result.groups['region']
    };
  }
  return {};
};
```

.. and finally my Jest test:

```
import { parseFilename } from './filenameParser';

test('parseFilename', () => {
  expect(parseFilename('page.md')).toStrictEqual({});
  expect(parseFilename('page.en.md')).toStrictEqual({ language: 'en', region: undefined });
  expect(parseFilename('page.another.en.md')).toStrictEqual({ language: 'en', region: undefined });
  expect(parseFilename('page.en-GB.md')).toStrictEqual({ language: 'en', region: 'GB' });
  expect(parseFilename('page.another.en-GB.md')).toStrictEqual({ language: 'en', region: 'GB' });
});
```

Unfortunately the fourth assertion fails:

[image: Fail]

When I debug the code the `const result` is just `null`.

## Now something for the X-Files

When I open a new `node` shell (Node.js v12.14.0) I can do this:

```
Welcome to Node.js v12.14.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const FILENAME_REGEX = /(?<=\.)(?<language>[a-z]{2})(\-(?<region>[A-Z]{2}))?(?=\.)/gim;
undefined
> FILENAME_REGEX.exec('page.en-GB.md');
[
  'en-GB',
  'en',
  '-GB',
  'GB',
  index: 5,
  input: 'page.en-GB.md',
  groups: [Object: null prototype] { language: 'en', region: 'GB' }
]
> FILENAME_REGEX.exec('page.en-GB.md');
null
> FILENAME_REGEX.exec('page.en-GB.md');
[
  'en-GB',
  'en',
  '-GB',
  'GB',
  index: 5,
  input: 'page.en-GB.md',
  groups: [Object: null prototype] { language: 'en', region: 'GB' }
]
> FILENAME_REGEX.exec('page.en-GB.md');
null
```

Why the heck is it every second time `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this is a bit an ugly designed API of JavaScript. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches) documentation:

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec() method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's lastIndex property (test() will also advance the lastIndex property). Note that the lastIndex property will not be reset when searching a different string, it will start its search at its existing lastIndex.

Especially ugly (IMHO) is that the index is not reset, when the string changes, what explains the failing test.

So if the modifier `g` is removed, the all tests are green.